# Letra maiúscula num SearchBar - Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-forms

Preciso ter a letra maiúscula num SearchBar, o código que consegui fazer que me pareceu mais próximo da realidade é essa abaixo, mas não deu certo:

```
//Pesquisa localmente a cada letra digitada
private void OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //Letra Maiúscula
    MainSearchBar.Text.ToUpper();
}
```

Declaração da `SearchBar`:

```
<!-- Pesquisa -->
<SearchBar x:Name="MainSearchBar" 
           Placeholder="Digite o nome do produto..." 
           Margin="10, 12, 10, 0" 
           BackgroundColor="LightGray" 
           TextChanged="OnTextChanged"/>
```

Comment: Ah sim, desculpe, estou utilizando assim: `<!-- Pesquisa -->
                <SearchBar x:Name="MainSearchBar"
                           Placeholder="Digite o nome do produto..." 
                           Margin="10, 12, 10, 0"
                           BackgroundColor="LightGray"
                           TextChanged="OnTextChanged"/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recebi uma ajuda de um colega que é bem simples e funcionou perfeitamente:

```
MainSearchBar.Text = MainSearchBar.Text.ToUpper();
```

Answer (score 1):

O evento em si não provê a possibilidade de alterar a entrada do usuário, pois ele é disparado depois que o texto já foi alterado.

Isso está longe de ser a solução ideal, eu particularmente não recomendaria, inclusive. Mas para fazer o seu código funcionar seria assim:

```
private void OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.NewTextValue))
        ((SearchBar)sender).Text = e.NewTextValue.ToUpper();
}
```

### Alternativas

#### Usar um componente que tratasse a entrada dos dados

[No GitHub tem o componente 'CapitalizeKeyboard'](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/blob/dev/docs/Effects/Entry/CapitalizeKeyboard.md), por exemplo. Ele fornece a possibilidade de forçar a entrada em maiúsculas.

Veja um exemplo dele funcionando no android e iOS:

[image: exemplo iOS] [image: exemplo Android]

#### MVVM - Usando um `ValueConverter`

Você usaria esse `Converter`:

```
public class CapitalizeTextConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Capitalize(value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Capitalize(value);
    }

    private object Capitalize(object value)
    {
        if (value == null || !(value is string) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value)) 
            return value;

        return value.ToString().ToUpper();
    }
}
```

Nesse caso, sua declaração no `XAML` ficaria assim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:App.Converters"
             xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:App.ViewModels"
             x:Class="App.Views.SettingsPage">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <converter:CapitalizeTextConverter x:Key="CapitalizeTextConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewModel:MyViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <StackLayout>
        ... 
        <SearchBar Text="{Binding SearchText, Converter={StaticResource CapitalizeTextConverter}}"
                   SearchCommand="{Binding SearchCommand}"/>
        ... 
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Você precisaria da ViewModel para tratar o dado em si. Você poderia declará-la assim:

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string searchText;
    public string SearchText
    {
        get{ return searchText; }
        set
        {
            if(value != searchText)
            {
                searchText = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SearchText");
            }
        }
    }

    public Command SearchCommand { get; set; }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        SearchCommand = new Command(ExecuteSearch);
    }

    private void ExecuteSearch()
    {
        // Aqui você faria a lógica da busca como desejasse.
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

#### MVVM - Usando bindings e tratando as captulares na ViewModel (Recomendável).

Nesse caso, a declaração da searchbar no `XAML` estaria mais limpa e desacoplada (além de não precisar do *ValueConverter*):

```
<SearchBar Text="{Binding SearchText}"
           SearchCommand="{Binding SearchCommand}"/>
```

Sua ViewModel trataria o dado recebido na invocação do comando de busca (ou seja, no método `ExecuteSearch`) como você desejasse. Nesse caso essa parte da lógica ficaria totalmente transparente para o usuário (e para a view) e sua regra de negócio ficaria 'testável':

```
private void ExecuteSearch()
{
    var texto = SearchText?.ToUpper();

    if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(texto))
    {
        // Aqui você faria a busca como desejasse.
    }
}
```

Espero ter ajudado.